# setting a Twig variable

Tags: twig

Is it possible to set a option value to a twig variable?

I want to accomplish something like this.

```
<select>
    <option value="10">10</option> 
</select>

{% set optVal = option value here %}//don't know if this is possible.

{% if optVal %}
     //do something here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: are you trying to 'set optVal' after user selects a value ?

Comment: yes. I want to use that value to test against data in my database. I am using twig to display the data from the db.

Comment: You can't. Twig is rendered serverside. You would need to use `javascript`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37615818/446594)

Comment: Thank you. I got it to with with the javascript. I was just wondering if it was possible the way i showed in the example.